# Python method lookup, static vs. instance

Tags: python, static, monkeypatching

Until like one hour ago, I was convinced that in python `Foo ().bar ()` was nothing more than a short hand for `Foo.bar (Foo () )` which passes the instance as first parameter. In this example the last two lines do (apparently) the same thing:

```
class Foo (object):
    def bar (self): print "baz"

qux = Foo ()
qux.bar ()
Foo.bar (qux)
```

But now I have a class Animal that has a static method populate() that returns a list of all animals known to man. Also each instance of Animal has a method populate() that fills the properties of the instance with random values.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import random

animals = [ ("Bella", "cow"), ("Spike", "dog"), ("José", "iguana"), ("Tux", "penguin") ]

class Animal (object):
    @staticmethod
    def populate (*args): return map (lambda x: Animal (*x), animals)

    def __init__ (self, name = None, species = None):
        def bar (): self.name, self.species = random.choice (animals)
        self.name = name
        self.species = species
        self.populate = bar

    def __repr__ (self): return "%s of species %s" % (self.name, self.species)

print Animal.populate ()
print Animal ("Pinky", "mouse")
qux = Animal ()
qux.populate ()
print qux
```

The code works fine, but what made me suspicious was the fact that `print Animal.populate (qux)` called the static populate method (and hence returned a list and did not populate poor qux). So apparently my conviction that `Foo ().bar ()` was nothing more than a short hand for `Foo.bar (Foo () )` is wrong.

This raises various questions for me:

1. What happens when I call `Foo ().bar ()`?
2. What happens when I call `Foo.bar (Foo () )`?
3. Is there an internal difference between the both?
4. Am I missing some fundamental concept of python?
5. If you had to write a class whose static populate method does something else than the populate method invoked over an instance of this class, which would be the way to go?

(Yes it must be the same name.)

Comment: A more interesting title would be "Python method lookup, static vs. instance". You may get more answers using that terminology, it's a bit more technical and attractive.

Comment: @Santiago Thank you for the input. I changed the title.

Comment: All the extra spaces around the `()` makes my eyes hurt

Comment: De gustibus non est diputandum. Mine hurt with things like `", ".join(map(lambda x:"%s"%x,zip(*pairs)[1]))`. How does whitespace gusto relate to method lookup?

Comment: I'm not sure of the point of having a staticmethod if you never call it from an instance. Are you confusing this with static method from a different language perhaps? classmethod makes more sense here

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but in pyhton staticmethod and classmethod only differ whether the class is passed as first argument or not. How could I possibly invoke a static (class) method from an instance as you suggest? Isn't the idea of a static (class) method that it is invoked from a class rather than an instance?

Comment: `qux.populate` will always call the instance method since you are unconditionally setting it. `qux.__class__.populate()` would call the method on the class

Comment: using `*args` just to make populate sometimes work like a staticmethod and sometimes like a classmethod seems like a poor design to me. Maybe it is better to write some tests to clarify how you will be using this class and maybe a fresh approach will become apparent

Comment: Thank you, I think little by little I am beginning to grok this in fullness.

Comment: The idea of using this is quite as in the example. I have a class that represents objects I have in the presistence leayer (DB or something else). Think about a light-weight ORM. When I call class.load I want an array of all instances I find in the DB. If I call load from an instance, I want to populate this same instance with persisted data depending on some member variables set in this instance.

Comment: BTW it also works without `*args`. The parameter was a leftover from another test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the difference between Foo().bar(), Foo.bar(Foo()) and Foo.bar() (as an answer because I signed up yesterday and can't post comments yet) - this is because of Python(<3.0)'s concept of 'bound' and 'unbound' methods - it strictly requires that, except with @staticmethod or @classmethod, method calls have an instance associated with them. There's not really any easier way to explain it than just something you have to remember. 
Thankfully, this has changed in Python 3 - the concept of 'bound' and 'unbound' methods as separate things has gone, and Foo.bar() works just fine for your example.

Comment: I just moved from python2.7 to python3.2 and now I am experiences less "surprises" than before.

Answer (score 2):

Static methods and class methods are [special descriptors](http://docs.python.org/howto/descriptor.html#static-methods-and-class-methods). Since the descriptor's `__get__()` method's  arguments include both the class and any relevant instance, they can screw with the arguments to the method in any way they like.

Comment: Thank you. I will read the link and most probably come back with more questions.

Answer (score 0):

`qnx.populate()` first looks on the instance `qnx` for `populate`. If that is not there the `__mro__` is followed until something called `populate` is found.

`Animals.populate(qnx)` is skipping the first step in the above lookup

Comment: Thank you very much. I will need some time to digest this.

Comment: Is there a way to trace with MRO in python?

Comment: @Hyperboreus, the class has an `__mro__` attribute

Comment: One thing I don't understand. Using `class Foo (object): <newline> def bar (*args): print "baz"`, why do `Foo ().bar ()` and `Foo.bar (Foo () )` work, but `Foo.bar ()` does not?

Comment: @Hyperboreus, The latter is an unbound method. This is more obvious if you follow the usual convention of using an explicit self. `def bar(self, *args)`. The first 2 are passing an instance as `self`. The first because it is a bound method, the second because you are passing an instance explicitly. Writing `def bar(*args)` does not let you get away with not passing in an instance, it merely disguises it as the first element of `args`

Comment: Understood. And good to hear that python 3 ended the bound/unbound paradigm.